# issue in excel exporting with chrome12

Tags: asp.net, excel, google-chrome

I have a asp.net web application which exports the data into an excel sheet. This function is perfectly working in firefox, IE and chrome5.XX But not in chrome 12.XXX..
it generated the file as report.aspx insted of report.xls.
any idea..?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: let me see inside my crystal ball... hmmm... no, I can't see anything (did you *really* wanted us to *guess* without any information about how you are doing your export?)

Answer (score 0):

Even I had the same problem and it is working fine with the below code:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.xls");
```